# Quantile-Quantile Plot using Seaborn and SciPy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn, normal-distribution

Can anyone give me a way to do a [qq plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) in Seaborn as a test for normality of data? Or failing that, at least in matplotlib.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html

Answer (score 21):

After reading the wikipedia article, I understand that the Q-Q plot is a plot of the quantiles of two distributions against each other.

`numpy.percentile` allows to obtain the percentile of a distribution. Hence you can call `numpy.percentile` on each of the distributions and plot the results against each other.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(5,5,250)
b = np.random.rayleigh(5,250)

percs = np.linspace(0,100,21)
qn_a = np.percentile(a, percs)
qn_b = np.percentile(b, percs)

plt.plot(qn_a,qn_b, ls="", marker="o")

x = np.linspace(np.min((qn_a.min(),qn_b.min())), np.max((qn_a.max(),qn_b.max())))
plt.plot(x,x, color="k", ls="--")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the approach above samples from a normal distribution and hence the plot is an approximation, while usually the theoretical quantities are used for a QQ-plot. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Comment: In fact, @Harvs was also explicitly asking about a way to compare to the theoretical distribution.

Answer (score 12):

Try [`statsmodels.api.qqplot()`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html).

Using same data as above, this example shows a normal distribution plotted against a normal distribution, resulting in fairly straight line:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

a = np.random.normal(5, 5, 250)
sm.qqplot(a)
plt.show()
```

[image: qq normal]

This example shows a Rayleigh distribution plotted against normal distribution, resulting in a slightly concave curve:

```
a = np.random.rayleigh(5, 250)
sm.qqplot(a)
plt.show()
```

[image: qq rayleigh]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this still recent, but I notice that neither of the answers really addresses the question, which asks how to do qq-plots with scipy and seaborn, but doesn't mention statsmodels. In fact, qq-plots are available in scipy under the name probplot:

```
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
stats.probplot(x, plot=sns.mpl.pyplot)
```

The plot argument to probplot can be anything that has a `plot` method and a `text` method. Probplot is also quite flexible about the kinds of theoretical distributions it supports.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, this generates a "probability plot" which is not a qq plot

Comment: it should be `stats.probplot(x, dist='norm', plot=plt)`

Comment: True, @gregV, but `dist='norm'` is the default setting. Hence the this is a little more concise. Specifying `plot=sns.mpl.pyplot` is because @Harvs had asked for a way to get these plots with seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

At [seaborn-qqplot addon documentation](https://seaborn-qqplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) an example is shown. [Also see](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn-qqplot/).

Working with pycharm and windows 10 I had difficulties installing the library with:

```
pip install seaborn-qqplot
```

in my virtual environment. The import line:

```
from seaborn_qqplot import pplot
```

was not recognized.

With (commands for PyCharm): file -> settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> + (Install)  I could import pplot from seaborn_qqplot and could create a Quantile - Quantile plot.